# MySQL: How to create a partial index on a boolean/tinyint column?

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
CREATE TABLE participations (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    participant_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    prize_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    win tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX participant_id (participant_id),
    INDEX prize_id (prize_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I've these queries:

```
SELECT prize_id, participant_id FROM participations WHERE win=1;
SELECT participant_id FROM participations WHERE prize_id=1 AND win=1;
```

Can one create a partial index like ([PostgreSQL-style](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3)) ?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX prize_win ON participations (prize_id) WHERE win=1;
```

__

Plan B: Having a table "winners" (prize_id, participant_id).

Answer (score 12):

No, MySQL does not support partial indexes of this nature.

If people refer to "partial indexes" in MySQL, they're referring to text "prefix indexes" where only a certain number of leading characters are indexed rather than the whole value. For example, an index could be made by only indexing the first 5 characters.

If you're looking for a performance boost because it's not using both `win` and `prize_id` columns (though I see you don't currently have `win` indexed), you could create a composite index over `(win, prize_id)` (in that order) so that it would filter values by `win` first, then look at the remaining `prize_id` value.

If you're instead looking for a partial index simply for the purposes of decreasing size/memory usage of that index, this would unfortunately have the opposite effect.

Comment: Concerning the bigger size usage of the index, it may have been true in 2011 when this answer was posted, however it's not the case anymore. 

According to the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html):

`If names in the column usually differ in the first 10 characters, this index should not be much slower than an index created from the entire name column. Also, using column prefixes for indexes can make the index file much smaller, which could save a lot of disk space and might also speed up INSERT operations.`

Comment: @AbuJunayd I think you misunderstood. The comparison is between [an index that does not include every row](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index) (which the asker described and MySQL does not currently support) and a composite index that covers an additional column. If the asker sought to reduce the size of the index on one column by only indexing a subset of rows, surely adding a second column to the index (and still indexing all rows) would instead increase its size.