# Doctrine's "options" property in @UniqueConstraint not working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

### Context

I'm using Doctrine version 2.5.0 and I have two entities: `Group` and `Item`. I'm trying to create an unique constraint so that `Items` cannot have the same `position` in a `Group`:

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(uniqueConstraints={
*            @UniqueConstraint(name="position", columns={"group_id", "position"})
*       )
*/
class Item {
    ...
}
```

This works well.

---

### Problem

I added an `active` field to the Item entity, so instead of deleting an `Item`, I 'inactivate' it. But now the unique constraint doesn't work anymore, since the `Item` stays in the database with his `Group` reference and his `position`.

---

### Attempts

Looking at the Doctrine [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint), I've discovered that I can use the `options` property with a where clause in the `@UniqueConstraint`:

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(uniqueConstraints={
*            @UniqueConstraint(name="position", columns={"group_id", "position"},
*                              options={"where":"(active = 1)"})}
*       )
*/
class Item {
    ...
}
```

But the I get the same error as before:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '1-1' for key 'position'

Here is my deletion code:

```
$item->setActive(false);
$this->_em->persist($item);
$this->_em->flush();

foreach ($item->getNextItems() as $nextItem) {
    $nextItem->setPosition($nextItem->getPosition() - 1);
    $this->_em->persist($nextItem);
}

$this->_em->flush();
```

Any idea why the `options` property is not working?

---

**Update**

I realised a strange behaviour. Every time I run the command `./doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force` it recreates the index:

```
DROP INDEX position ON Item;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX position ON Item (group_id, position);
```

But once I remove the `options` property and run the command, I get:

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current
>   entity metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I read over this from the Doctrine [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint):

> SQL WHERE condition to be used for partial indexes. It will only have effect on supported platforms.

After [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156687/mysql-how-to-create-a-partial-index-on-a-boolean-tinyint-column):

> MySQL does not support partial indexes of this nature

My solution is to check if the `Item` is really unique in a [LifeCycleEvent](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) inside the entity:

```
/**
 * @PostPersist @PostUpdate
 */
public function checkUnicity(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();

    // checking unicity here
    // throw exception if not

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have data already in database and then after you are adding unique constraint first please check in database that you have unique values or not.

Comment: They are already unique. Anyways, if not I would get an error when running `orm:schema-tool:update`